# Davis.js & scrollTo

Tags: jquery, scrollto, pushstate

I'm using Davis.js and and Ariel Flesler's scrolLTo plugin. I'm trying to have the window scrollTo a div on my page:

```
var app = Davis(function () {
          this.get('/products', function (req) {
              $(window).scrollTo( '#products', 800 );
          })
        })

        app.start();
```

This is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you jsfiddle an example of this not working, or explain what you mean by "not working"? Are there any errors?  Is the code that executes the call to `Davis()` not running? Is the function that executes the `scrollTo()` not running? Does a dinosaur come and eat the machine running the code when you open the webpage? Does the code sit on the couch all day, not getting a job and eats all your food?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that an element with id 'products' is on the page when that route is ran?

It is difficult to try and provide an answer with so little information, do you have a simplified test case that is easy to rerun.

I can't think of any reason why Davis wouldn't work well with scollTo.